# Django не удаеться зарегистрировать функцию приемник

Tags: python, django

Регистрирую функцию-получатель (один в один как в документации).
Файл add_post.py:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from blog.models import Post


@receiver(post_save, sender=Post)
def add_post(post, **kwargs):
   print("Creates is" + kwargs['created'])
   print("Created post is " + post.title)
```

Файл views.py:

```
 from blog.siganls.add_post import add_post

 if createform.is_valid():
        new_post = createform.save(commit=False)
        new_post.blog_id = blog.id
        new_post.save()
    return render(request,
                  self.template_name,
                  {
                      'postform': createform,
                  })
```

Вываливает ошибку:

> TypeError: add_post() missing 1 required positional argument: 'post'

По трейсбеку видно что ошибка в строчке:

```
new_post.save()
```

Подскажите, куда смотреть?

Если убрать строчку

```
from blog.siganls.add_post import add_post
```

то функция не вызывается вообще.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в функции

```
def add_post(post, **kwargs):
   print("Creates is" + kwargs['created'])
   print("Created post is " + post.title)
```

первый аргумент должен называться не post, а instance.